# How to clear cache in Openshift

Tags: php, web-services, web-config

I am developing a iphone app and I am using Openshift as web services for my app. My app will call the web services every 10 seconds however my app often get the old responses from web service. I don't understand why but I think this server was cached. Is this right? Can you please help me step by steps so that I can clear cache my Openshift server? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Openshift PHP cartridges use a cache. You can disable it with rhc using this command:

```
rhc env-set OPENSHIFT_PHP_APC_ENABLED=false --app <app>
```

Hope that helps...